# Complement for a Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

In a matrix, there are some non-zero elements same as: aA=

[image]

Also, there is a list such as:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ii, jj, kk};
```

I want to access to elements of the list which are not in the matrix. (I mean: 'c','d','g','jj') I use Complement to this work:

```
Complement[aA, list]
```

But Complement doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten the matrix first.

```
aA = {{a, b, 0}, {e, f, 0}, {ii, 0, kk}};
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ii, jj, kk};
Complement[list, Flatten@aA]
```

> {c, d, g, jj}

Comment: I think for my goal, I must write: Complement[list, Flatten@aA]

Comment: @mostafa Oh yes, I didn't read carefully.